# How does one create procedurally generated visualizations in iOS, outside the scope of creating a game?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, scenekit, core-motion

I want to be able to create a similar visualization as to that of the mobile app SweatCoin.

Image Reference: https://immortalallure.com/2018/06/26/can-you-really-turn-your-sweat-into-money-my-first-2-weeks-using-the-sweatcoin-app/

They are procedurally generating a sort of "terrain" lattice as the user moves the device. I assume they are using the accel/gyro from CoreMotion to track the device and produce the visuals in real time. However, I cannot put my finger on how the actual terrain is being produced (Full disclosure: my expertise is not in game development).

What Swift modules are needed to accomplish this visualization?

I've tried playing around with CALayers to accomplish this, but have not had any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing the 3D "terrain" is accomplished using [SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/scenekit/), the "terrain" is a low poly 3D model of mountains and a valley (with some particle animations) that is loaded into a SceneKit `SCNView` scene. That `SCNView` is then implemented as a subview of the `ViewController` view.

With regard to the animation, its most likely using [Core-Motion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion) to connect the gyroscope and accelerometer motion to the rotation of the root node within the SCNView to achieve the perspective effect as the user moves the device around.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, I will try this out!